# Rails 4.1 -> 4.2 has caused an after_create callback that sends an e-mail to stop working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `Note` model (`note.rb`) I have the snippet below that is being triggered by an Active Record callback:

```
def creation_email
  case self.notable_type
  when 'Application'
    NoteMailer.run('application', self)
  when 'Appointment'
    NoteMailer.run('appointment', self)
  end

  self.inbounded = 1
  self.save
end
```

In the `NoteMailer` I have another switch statement to send different e-mail templates based on the polymorphic `notable_type`.  Here is that snippet:

```
  def run(type, note)
    @note = note

    case type
    when 'application'
      app = Application.find(@note.notable_id)

      app.users.each do |user|
        if user.id != @note.user.id && user.email
          mail(to: user.email,
               from: @note.user.name + " <application." + app.id.to_s + "." + user.id.to_s + "@mail.mysecretdomain.com>",
               subject: "my secret subject",
               template_name: "application.html.erb").deliver_now
        end   
      end
    when 'appointment'
      a = Appointment.find(@note.notable_id)

      a.users.each do |user|
        if user.id != @note.user.id && user.email
          mail(to: user.email,
               from: note.user.name + " <appointment." + a.id.to_s + "." + user.id.to_s + "@mail.mysecretdomain.com>",
               subject: "my secret subject",
               template_name: "appointment.html.erb").deliver_now
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Since upgrading to Rails 4.2 from Rails 4.1, the e-mails are not sending out as they used to.

What could be causing this problem?  I did change `mail(..).deliver` to `mail(..).deliver_now`.

I've tried adding `puts "test"` in the run method at the top, and it does not put the string to the console.  No errors at all are thrown

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `run` is never called. You need to call `deliver_now` in the proper place.

Try this :

```
def creation_email
  case self.notable_type
  when 'Application'
    NoteMailer.run('application', self).deliver_now
  when 'Appointment'
    NoteMailer.run('appointment', self).deliver_now
  end

  self.inbounded = 1
  self.save
end
```

Instead of calling `deliver_now` in your Mailer.

See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-1-to-rails-4-2